# Can I redefine a built-in type inside a namespace?

Tags: c++, types, namespaces

I would like to redefine the built-in type `bool` inside a library's namespaces and classes because they need to work differently but I would like to keep the name `bool` : `ex::bool`, `ex::false`, `ex::true`. But my compiler doesn't let me do that, I tried something like this :

```
namespace ex {
    typedef uint8_t bool;
    const uint8_t false = 0;
}
```

I also tried prefixing `bool` and `false` with `ex::` inside the definition to emphasis the fact that it is in ex but it doesn't work. What could I do to have `ex::bool` ?

Answer (score 4):

> What could I do to have `ex::bool` ?

You can't do anything. `bool` and `false` are hardwired with meaning by the language specification and are intrinsic keywords. You can't change their meaning any more than you can change the meaning of `0`, `if` or `while`.

Choosing different names (such as `Bool` and `False`) is your only option.

Comment: Can I keep their meaning but put them into my namespace for consistency ?

Comment: @linternetsansfil - No. Keywords are reserved symbols in the language. You can't relegate them to another scope or really do anything with them other than use as intended.